# react-native-audio-recorder-player , audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder() crahs app

Tags: android, react-native

react-native-audio-recorder-player, library for use in my project to record audio.
When I start recording everything works fine, but close the application when I call the function to stop recording the audio "audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder ()".
It works perfectly on IOS (emulator and real device), and on Android emulator, but, it doesn't work on real android device.

What could be the cause of this error and how could it be resolved?

```
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^2.6.0-rc3",
```

hooks for control

```
  const [record, setRecord] = useState(false);
```

start record function

```
async function handleRecord() {
    try {
      const permissions = await getPermissions();

      if (permissions) {
        const path = Platform.select({
          ios: `audio-${new Date().getTime()}.m4a`,
          android: `sdcard/audio-${new Date().getTime()}.mp3`
        });

        const audioSet = {
          AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,
          AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
          AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
          AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
          AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac
        };

        const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder(path, audioSet);

        setRecord(true);

        audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener(e => {
          return;
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
    }
  }
```

stop record function

```
async function onStopRecord() {
    try {
      const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
      audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();

      setRecord(false);




       setFiles([
        ...files,
        {
          uri: result,
          type: "audio/mpeg",
          name: `audio-${new Date().getTime()}.mp3`
        }
      ]);  
    }catch(error){
      Alert.alert(
        "Erro",
        error
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? Can you post your complete code? I am not able to play it on my IOS simulator.

Comment: Sorry friend, i did not find the solution. Hope you can find another way on your code !

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to file format. You save files as

```
const path = Platform.select({
          ios: `audio-${new Date().getTime()}.m4a`,
          android: `sdcard/audio-${new Date().getTime()}.mp3`
        });
```

as m4a, and mp3

But encode as different format in AudioSet

```
const audioSet = {
          AudioEncoderAndroid: AudioEncoderAndroidType.AAC,===>here
          AudioSourceAndroid: AudioSourceAndroidType.MIC,
          AVEncoderAudioQualityKeyIOS: AVEncoderAudioQualityIOSType.high,
          AVNumberOfChannelsKeyIOS: 2,
          AVFormatIDKeyIOS: AVEncodingOption.aac ===>here
        };
```

Remove AudioSet for test. Everything should works fine. After that put correct format for AudioSet